# compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: build.gradle, react-native-reanimated

A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Android/build.gradle

```
 ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 23
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        // playServicesVersion = "18.0.1"
    }
```

Android/app/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ideabilisim.medlineapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Android/build.gradle

```
android { 
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '28.0.3')
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 28)
        compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this specific version in your packages.json

"react-native-reanimated": "2.2.4",

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your "compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion" outside the debugConfig.

As this:

From

```
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ideabilisim.medlineapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

To

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 28)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Unity project, I upgraded Unity and got the same error while building for Android.

The issue was with gradle version. In my project there was gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties , where there was a too old gradle version specified in the distributionUrl:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

I updated it to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

And also checked out the build.gradle (main project) classpath to be LOWER than the version specified in the distributionUrl:

```
    dependencies {
        // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
        // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
        // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
        // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

Please note also, if you are using Unity, that this can be set from Preferences > External Tools .